# How to measure RU in DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, query-performance, azure-cosmosdb

Given that Azure DocumentDB uses Requests Units as a measurement for throughput I would like to make sure my queries utilize the least amount of RUs as possible to ncrease my throughput. Is there a tool that will tell me how many RUs a query will take and if the query is actually using an index or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [DocumentDb Studio](https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio) which shows the response header that provide the RUs on every query.

[image]

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Keep in mind that if your query has more than one page (using `executeNext()`), the RUs are on each call so you'd need to sum them up to account for all of the RUs. My documentdb-utils wraps the Azure-provided node.js SDK to do things like sum up all of the RUs, give you latency stats, and automatically re-try operations when they are timed out or hit your RU budget. I've considered porting the library to .NET.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone can you provide us with a link to your SDK? Why not contribute these solutions to the Microsoft SDKs or does this sit on top of that SDK?

Comment: I do contribute bug and document fixes to the DocumentDB node.js SDK. I'm currently the 7th highest contributor and 5 of the 6 with more contributions are all Azure employed. The reason that I have created complementary tools rather than submit pull requests to the Azure codebase is that those tools might not be everyone's cup of tea. Also, the node.js SDK is a relatively thin wrapper around the REST API matching all of it's semantics. If I were to design documentdb-utils from scratch to directly hit the REST API, I would probably have built something just like what Azure did. It's nicely done

Comment: As for links, I actually have 4 complementary tools.

1. [documentdb-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils). Wrapper of the node.js SDK with auto retry plus a bunch of other useful utilities.
2. [documentdb-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-mock). Mocks the server-side API for testing sprocs locally and in continuous build systems like TravisCI.
3. [documentdb-lumenize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-lumenize). Aggregation engine running in a sproc.
4. [sql-from-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-from-mongo). Query documentdb with MongoDB syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As you discovered, certain tools will provide RU's upon completion of a query. This is also available programmatically, as the `x-ms-request-charge` header is returned in the response, and easily retrievable via the DocumentDB SDKs.

For example, here's a snippet showing RU retrieval using JS/node:

```js
var queryIterator = client.queryDocuments(collLink, querySpec );
queryIterator.executeNext(function (err, results, headers) {
  if (err) {
    // deal with error...
  } else {
    // deal with payload...
    var ruConsumed = headers['x-ms-request-charge'];
  }
});
```

As far as your question regarding indexing, and determining if a property is indexed (which should then answer your question about a query using or not using an index): You may query the collection, which returns the indexing details in the response header.

For example: given some path `dbs/<databaseId>/colls/<collectionId>`:

```js
var collLink = 'dbs/' + databaseId+ '/colls/'+ collectionId;

client.readCollection(collLink, function (err, coll) {
    if (err) {
        // deal with error

    } else {
        // compare indexingPolicy with your property, to see if it's included or excluded
        // this just shows you what these properties look like
        console.log("Included: " + JSON.stringify(coll.indexingPolicy.includedPaths))
        console.log("Excluded: " + JSON.stringify(coll.indexingPolicy.excludedPaths))
    }
});
```

You'll see `includedPaths` and `excludedPaths` looking something like this, and you can then search for your given property in any way you see fit:

```
Included: [{"path":"/*","indexes":[{"kind":"Range","dataType":"Number","precision":-1},{"kind":"Hash","dataType":"String","precision":3}]}]
Excluded: []
```

Comment: great answer! I upvoted it, but selected mine as the answer as I was specifically asking for a tool.

Comment: just a side note; the Azure Management Portal Query Explorer also tells you the RUs for a query.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the emulator with the trace collection option turned on.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator

I was trying to profile LINQ aggregate queries, which currently seems to be impossible with c# SDK.

Using the trace output from the emulator I was able to identify the request charges and a host of other metrics. There is a lot of data to wade through through. 
I found the request charge stored under this event key
`DocDBServer/Transport_Channel_Processortask/Genericoperation`

Example output:
`ThreadID="141,928" FormattedMessage="EndRequest DocumentServiceId localhost, ResourceType 2, OperationType 15, ResourceId 91M7AL+QPQA=, StatusCode 200, HRESULTHex 0, ResponseLength 61, Duration 70,546, HasQuery 1, PartitionId a4cb495b-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be, ReplicaId 1, ConsistencyLevel 3, RequestSessionToken 0:594, ResponseSessionToken 594, HasContinuation 0, HasPreTrigger 0, HasPostTrigger 0, IsFeedUnfiltered 0, IndexingDirective 5, XDate Fri, 09 Jun 2017 08:49:03 GMT, RetryAfterMilliseconds 0, MaxItemCount -1, ActualItemCount 1, ClientVersion 2017-02-22, UserAgent Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.13.58.2, RequestLength 131, NetworkBucket 2, SubscriptionId 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Region South Central US, IpAddress 192.168.56.0, ChannelProtocol RNTBD, RequestCharge 51.424, etc...`

This can then be correlated with data from another event which contains the query info:
`DocDBServer/ServiceModuletask/Genericoperation`

Note you need perfview to view the ETL log files. See here for more info:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/docs/documentdb-sdk_capture_etl.md