# Getting continuous 'Request rate is large' error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm pushing bunch of data in Cosmos DB using MongoDB NodeJS drivers. I'm running into the following error

`{"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}`

I realize this error occurs when the RU/s have exceeded the set threshold. I have partitioned my collection and set 2000 RU/s. I also have set an exponential backoff delay if that error occurs. It was working fine earlier i.e. it retried after a while if it ran into that error but succeeded after waiting. But currently it's consistently throwing the 'Request rate is large' even though I have a mechanism to try again after some delay. Any idea what might be going on and how can I resolve the issue?

Along with that is there a way to extract the raw response headers sent from cosmos DB using MongoDB NodeJS driver as I would like to extract `x-ms-retry-after-ms` and `x-ms-request-charge` headers.

Comment: Though increasing the RU/s has resolved the issue for now but I would like to decrease the RU/s back to what it was originally and understand why it wasn't working.

Comment: Track which queries are actually sent to cosmosDB. Pure inserts should be constant time so should give relatively stable throughput. Could it be you are reading something that is not indexed and which is burning away your RU-limit?

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46898763/272109) shows how to retrieve the return headers in node (the example I show there is for calling a stored procedure but should be similar for other functions like creating a document). Once you know the RU cost, then you can start looking into options for reducing RU cost (such as customizing your index policy to remove indexes on properties you don't perform searches on).

Comment: And my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35254433/272109) shows an example when executing a query, along with how to programmatically modify an index policy.

Comment: It looks like you already answered your question. You are exceeding the RU limit that you provisioned. If you don't believe that's accurate, you can aggregate the costs when your calls return and check for yourself.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for that, but I'm using mongo Node JS library. So that example won't work for me :(. To use that I suppose I have to use the document db npm package?

Comment: @JoshuaKrstic The issue I ran into was that I got that error continuously even though it send the request after like half a minute. Which I think should not happen.

Comment: @Zabi I'm fairly certain throttling happens in a minute-basis, i.e you are provisioned RUs per minute, and are throttled that way. 30 seconds seems normal
I would check your settings to be sure

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the raw header values from the .NET MongoDB.Driver library?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue @Zabi